# Fir filter Hamming window 161 order bandpass filter implementation

Tags: finite-impulse-response

I'm running an FIR filter hamming window order 161 bandpass with pass frequency range 20Hz-200Hz,  but output doesn't sound like the filter is working. It's just distorted output. Following is the code and 162 coefficients.
***note*** I'm using c5545 dsp booster pack whih comes with aic3206 codec inbuilt

```
coeff:-0.00035514,-0.0003342,-0.00031519,-0.0002975,-0.00028048,-0.00026346,-0.00024575,-0.00022664,-0.00020539,-0.00018126,-0.00015351,-0.00012138,-8.4119e-05,-4.0977e-05,8.7845e-06,6.5896e-05,0.00013107,0.00020499,0.00028834,0.00038174,0.00048581,0.00060111,0.00072817,0.00086749,0.0010195,0.0011846,0.0013631,0.0015553,0.0017614,0.0019817,0.0022161,0.0024647,0.0027276,0.0030046,0.0032955,0.0036002,0.0039183,0.0042495,0.0045934,0.0049494,0.005317,0.0056956,0.0060845,0.006483,0.0068902,0.0073053,0.0077274,0.0081555,0.0085887,0.0090258,0.0094659,0.0099077,0.01035,0.010792,0.011233,0.01167,0.012103,0.012531,0.012952,0.013366,0.013771,0.014165,0.014548,0.014918,0.015275,0.015617,0.015943,0.016253,0.016544,0.016817,0.017071,0.017304,0.017515,0.017705,0.017873,0.018018,0.018139,0.018237,0.01831,0.018359,0.018384,0.018384,0.018359,0.01831,0.018237,0.018139,0.018018,0.017873,0.017705,0.017515,0.017304,0.017071,0.016817,0.016544,0.016253,0.015943,0.015617,0.015275,0.014918,0.014548,0.014165,0.013771,0.013366,0.012952,0.012531,0.012103,0.01167,0.011233,0.010792,0.01035,0.0099077,0.0094659,0.0090258,0.0085887,0.0081555,0.0077274,0.0073053,0.0068902,0.006483,0.0060845,0.0056956,0.005317,0.0049494,0.0045934,0.0042495,0.0039183,0.0036002,0.0032955,0.0030046,0.0027276,0.0024647,0.0022161,0.0019817,0.0017614,0.0015553,0.0013631,0.0011846,0.0010195,0.00086749,0.00072817,0.00060111,0.00048581,0.00038174,0.00028834,0.00020499,0.00013107,6.5896e-05,8.7845e-06,-4.0977e-05,-8.4119e-05,-0.00012138,-0.00015351,-0.00018126,-0.00020539,-0.00022664,-0.00024575,-0.00026346,-0.00028048,-0.0002975,-0.00031519,-0.0003342,-0.00035514
```

**Edited**
code:

```
here is the code i used to convert the float coeff to fixed point int. still it doesn't work `  
    int N=17;
    int i,n;
    int index1=0;
    int index2=N;
    Int16 x[2*17];
    Int16 z[2*17];
    float y1new,y2new;
    I2S_writeLeft(0);
    I2S_writeRight(0);
    for(n=0;n<N;n++){
        coeff1[n]=round(coeff[n]*65536);
    }
    for ( sec = 0 ; sec < 30 ; sec++ )
            {
                for ( msec = 0 ; msec < 1000 ; msec++ )
                {
                    for ( sample = 0 ; sample < 8 ; sample++ )
                    {
                        /* Read 16-bit left channel Data */
                        I2S_readLeft(&data1);

                        /* Read 16-bit right channel Data */
                        I2S_readRight(&data2);


                        // As a new sample is received put it in two places
                        x[index1] = data1;
                        x[index2] = data1;
                        z[index1] = data2;
                        z[index2] = data2;
                        y1new=0;
                        y2new=0;
                        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                        y1new = y1new + coeff1[i]*x[index2-i];
                        y2new = y2new + coeff1[i]*z[index2-i];
                        }

                        index1 = (index1+1)%N;
                        index2 = index1+N;
                        data1=round(y1new/65536);
                        data2=round(y2new/65536);
                        /* Write 16-bit left channel Data */
                        I2S_writeLeft(data1);

                        /* Write 16-bit right channel Data */
                        I2S_writeRight(data2);
                    }
                    if(sw3Pressed == TRUE)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if(sw3Pressed == TRUE)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
```

`

Comment: Running your coeffs through `fvtool` in matlab the magnitude response looks like a lowpass filter and not a bandpass filter.

Comment: fl=20/16000;
fh=200*2/16000;
wn=[fl,fh];
b=fir1(16,wn,'bandpass');
csvwrite('coeff.h',b);
freqz(b,1,8192,16000) this is the code. they were generated by matlab

Answer (score 0):

Are you converting your coefficients to fixed point arithmetic? Maybe using a different Qi

EDIT: in your code you're writting a 32 bit floating point to a 16 bit function (at least the comment said that), probably the data from your codec is a 16 bit signed integer, so you need to convert your coeficients to integers and use fixed point arithmetic or convert your input to floating point and before writting to the output convert the output to an integer.

Comment: Please use comments to ask for clarification or more details.

Comment: No I just used the exact values generated by matlab in my code

Comment: Hi. What do you mean converting coefficients to integer? coeff values are less than 1

Comment: here is the code i used to convert the float coeff to fixed point int. still it doesn't work

Comment: Please look at the updated code at the top, changed code to implement fixed point bit conversion of coeffs. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response, fixed point arithmetic it's a little more complicated than just using an scaling factor. I'm not familiar with the codec you're using but lets assume that you have a signal with min/max voltage of 0/3.3V and you're using a 16 bit word data length, then 3.3V=65535, 1V=19859, and so on, this values will have a Qi associated and they must agree with the Qi of your coefficients. Try to check this page to understand a little more about this kind of operations:

http://x86asm.net/articles/fixed-point-arithmetic-and-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

You are using simply the Hamming window, not a filter with a Hamming window. You should first construct your basic sinc FIR, then multiply that, element wise, with the window. I don't know your requirements, but, for example, considering a sampling frequency of f0=1024, wc1=20, wc2=200, N=161, you get this impulse response:

```
[8.271000348697398*10^-4,-4.005705674586021*10^-5,5.295367364956051*10^-4,0.002393066734599492,0.004921821759432649,0.007220158325130953,0.0084484982317697,0.008134200102254907,0.006355564916819758,0.003727846760386229,0.001191040935974927,-3.278871443899911*10^-4,-2.57487614429514*10^-4,0.001396932356852497,0.004038250464381994,0.006680203763999663,0.008299599293271053,0.008212844748323863,0.006338876479588884,0.003248142380583287,-2.711429741182299*10^-5,-0.00235900216488486,-0.002937407884857515,-0.001579970520602455,0.001179041359396353,0.004261210947769193,0.006423313033375057,0.006711041312070553,0.004822626767540098,0.001245096116571405,-0.002895471634774978,-0.006225334281313758,-0.007621229501046421,-0.006635931356601788,-0.003691526664524759,4.028168191795361*10^-5,0.003039788619072278,0.003986857774999568,0.002259079382890321,-0.00180517205866057,-0.006986332153640902,-0.01159247473520406,-0.01406245832827337,-0.01355077422676097,-0.01027790911162972,-0.005505336605885325,-0.001124729222780451,0.001008192280744322,-2.357100534790199*10^-4,-0.004796321648929437,-0.01137276218296066,-0.01782648539361997,-0.02191901380400041,-0.02213498938322603,-0.01829459360740204,-0.01171705480380689,-0.004844333193264914,-4.236804040492915*10^-4,-5.143398798411001*10^-4,-0.005666274802851579,-0.01458268396492148,-0.02442822326901363,-0.03172662971439864,-0.03357694012510566,-0.02878200215535023,-0.01847909317325192,-0.006000691963658145,0.00406378955865214,0.007362737526424468,0.001380132111733462,-0.01339200434941131,-0.03314022101915493,-0.05146500752236288,-0.06103185117181874,-0.05570332124486767,-0.03253499829996801,0.006981302471188885,0.0568514539841485,0.1077829359401652,0.1493781500300271,0.1727347724935315,0.1727347724935315,0.1493781500300271,0.1077829359401652,0.0568514539841485,0.006981302471188885,-0.03253499829996801,-0.05570332124486767,-0.06103185117181874,-0.05146500752236288,-0.03314022101915493,-0.01339200434941131,0.001380132111733462,0.007362737526424468,0.00406378955865214,-0.006000691963658145,-0.01847909317325192,-0.02878200215535023,-0.03357694012510566,-0.03172662971439864,-0.02442822326901363,-0.01458268396492148,-0.005666274802851579,-5.143398798411001*10^-4,-4.236804040492915*10^-4,-0.004844333193264914,-0.01171705480380689,-0.01829459360740204,-0.02213498938322603,-0.02191901380400041,-0.01782648539361997,-0.01137276218296066,-0.004796321648929437,-2.357100534790199*10^-4,0.001008192280744322,-0.001124729222780451,-0.005505336605885325,-0.01027790911162972,-0.01355077422676097,-0.01406245832827337,-0.01159247473520406,-0.006986332153640902,-0.00180517205866057,0.002259079382890321,0.003986857774999568,0.003039788619072278,4.028168191795361*10^-5,-0.003691526664524759,-0.006635931356601788,-0.007621229501046421,-0.006225334281313758,-0.002895471634774978,0.001245096116571405,0.004822626767540098,0.006711041312070553,0.006423313033375057,0.004261210947769193,0.001179041359396353,-0.001579970520602455,-0.002937407884857515,-0.00235900216488486,-2.711429741182299*10^-5,0.003248142380583287,0.006338876479588884,0.008212844748323863,0.008299599293271053,0.006680203763999663,0.004038250464381994,0.001396932356852497,-2.57487614429514*10^-4,-3.278871443899911*10^-4,0.001191040935974927,0.003727846760386229,0.006355564916819758,0.008134200102254907,0.0084484982317697,0.007220158325130953,0.004921821759432649,0.002393066734599492,5.295367364956051*10^-4,-4.005705674586021*10^-5,8.271000348697398*10^-4]
```

You can multiply this, element wise, with your window. BTW, your window coefficients are downscaled by a factor of approximately `54.395`. This is the window I get:

```
[0.08000000000000002,0.0803502520611919,0.08140047486865282,0.08314906910628267,0.08559337195349054,0.08872966114023118,0.09255316061540825,0.09705804782001243,0.1022374625539182,0.1080835174228373,0.114587309849519,0.1217389356309068,0.1295275040206056,0.137941154313693,0.1469670739086153,0.156591517818667,0.1667998296033383,0.1775764636876553,0.1889050090355284,0.2007682141410511,0.2131480132996994,0.2260255541194192,0.2393812262297095,0.2531946911449826,0.267444913236722,0.2821101917672749,0.2971681939364971,0.3125959888909221,0.3283700826436701,0.3444664538519133,0.3608605903974197,0.377527526714465,0.3944418818082722,0.4115778979060787,0.4289094796819766,0.4464102339957886,0.4640535100854676,0.4818124401518113,0.4996599802736878,0.5175689515914672,0.5355120816959413,0.5534620461597044,0.5713915101477487,0.5892731700439097,0.6070797950297692,0.6247842685527005,0.6423596296199047,0.6597791138555558,0.6770161942585302,0.6940446215986537,0.7108384643899491,0.7273721483800123,0.7436204954953796,0.759558762183581,0.7751626770934887,0.7904084780365817,0.8052729481728389,0.8197334513661572,0.8337679666554523,0.8473551217889509,0.8604742257706041,0.8731053003690614,0.8852291105412222,0.8968271937240332,0.9078818879499261,0.9183763587430815,0.9282946247555586,0.9376215821042515,0.9463430273716122,0.9544456792351128,0.9619171986925085,0.9687462078521025,0.9749223072593993,0.9804360917337572,0.985279164690928,0.9894441509296694,0.9929247078629597,0.9957155351767122,0.9978123829012786,0.9992120578834522,0.9999124286491134,0.9999124286491134,0.9992120578834522,0.9978123829012786,0.9957155351767122,0.9929247078629597,0.9894441509296694,0.985279164690928,0.9804360917337572,0.9749223072593993,0.9687462078521025,0.9619171986925085,0.9544456792351128,0.9463430273716122,0.9376215821042515,0.9282946247555586,0.9183763587430815,0.9078818879499261,0.8968271937240332,0.8852291105412222,0.8731053003690614,0.8604742257706041,0.8473551217889509,0.8337679666554523,0.8197334513661572,0.8052729481728389,0.7904084780365817,0.7751626770934887,0.759558762183581,0.7436204954953796,0.7273721483800123,0.7108384643899491,0.6940446215986537,0.6770161942585302,0.6597791138555558,0.6423596296199047,0.6247842685527005,0.6070797950297692,0.5892731700439097,0.5713915101477487,0.5534620461597044,0.5355120816959413,0.5175689515914672,0.4996599802736878,0.4818124401518113,0.4640535100854676,0.4464102339957886,0.4289094796819766,0.4115778979060787,0.3944418818082722,0.377527526714465,0.3608605903974197,0.3444664538519133,0.3283700826436701,0.3125959888909221,0.2971681939364971,0.2821101917672749,0.267444913236722,0.2531946911449826,0.2393812262297095,0.2260255541194192,0.2131480132996994,0.2007682141410511,0.1889050090355284,0.1775764636876553,0.1667998296033383,0.156591517818667,0.1469670739086153,0.137941154313693,0.1295275040206056,0.1217389356309068,0.114587309849519,0.1080835174228373,0.1022374625539182,0.09705804782001243,0.09255316061540825,0.08872966114023118,0.08559337195349054,0.08314906910628267,0.08140047486865282,0.0803502520611919,0.08000000000000002]
```

---

[edit]

You are using an unreasonably small bandwidth (that implies an even more unreasonably small transition width) compared to your sampling frequency. You should either choose a smaller sampling frequency, or a higher order. For example, using a Kaiser window and letting Kaiser determine the order, with a side-lobe attenuation of 60dB and a transition width of 40*2/16000, I get an order of 1451:

[image: impfreq]

And here's a zoom on the passband on the graph on the right (x-axis is in samples, 8192/2 being Nyquist):

[image: zoom]

As far as I see it, you have 4 options: quit, go on blindly ahead, lower sampling frequency, use a (much) higher order -- for Hamming, you may need a higher order than for a Kaiser, and for an equiripple you'll most probably achieve a lower one than Kaiser, and an even lower one if you can tolerate a higher ripple in the passband.

Comment: ['code'] fl=20/16000;
fh=200*2/16000;
wn=[fl,fh];
b=fir1(16,wn,'bandpass');
csvwrite('coeff.h',b);
freqz(b,1,8192,16000) here is the matlab code i used to generate those coefficients

Comment: Seems like I've only one choice that is to reduce sampling rate to probably 4000 or so. I can't increase the order since it would induce latency for processing.

Comment: Do you need that high a sampling rate? for 200Hz, a 512Hz sampling rate would work just fine, 1k, or 1024 for (quite a bit of) extra room. Note that, according to my example (f0=16kHz), results in N=1451, which means for 4kHz => 1451/4 ~ 363. 4k seems too much, but, of course, you know your requirements.

Comment: well, I need atleast 4000hz for my application as my bandpass can go to 1500hz later but now i'm cutting at 200hz. But the issue is even I decrease the sample rate to 8000 and filter order to 16, still it's not working. please look at the updated code, do you think my float coeff conversion to 16bit integer is right?

Comment: Since your order didn't work and needed to be *increased*, or the order kept but the sampling rate *decreased*, you can't expect to reduce both and have it working, that's very counter-intuitive. And your code doesn't deal with creating the filter, only with the filtering process. So, rather than going on blindly, woudn't it be better for you to state your requirements and then see what filter can come out of it, instead of poking around at numbers, aimlessly?